# OpenMP in windows and Linux(CentOS)

Tags: linux, multithreading, openmp, mex

I have a pretty big piece of code written in C++ and integrated into MATLAB via mex functionality. It was originally written in a windows machine but now that I run it on the Linux machine, it gives wrong result.

Is anyone aware of any difference between how Linux and Windows handles OS. It usually involves

> #omp pragma for

I couldn't post the code here.  I would really appreciate some insights into what might be wrong .

Comment: Maybe the error message might help. Btw. it is `#pragma omp for` and when you are not linking with the openMP it acts as comment in the code with warning during compilation. The problem might arise when you call `omp_xyz` functions like `omp_set_num_threads`, they do not exists.

Comment: Do serial versions on both platforms return the same results? Without any code, preferably a [mcve] and not the code itself, the question is too broad.

Comment: I am aware that it is a broad question. yes serial version gives the same result. There are a lot of places where they are being parallelized. So, I am not sure which one is actually responsible for the wrong result.

Comment: There is no error message. It is just giving the wrong result.

Comment: @AviGinsburg I was wondering if there is ant difference between the two, which i should be aware of.

Comment: Disable/enable each parallel section until you've narrowed it down to the one that doesn't return the same result. Vis-à-vis differences between Windows/Linux, it's also a difference between different compiler implementations of the OMP standard (and which one, etc.). So you should also specify which compilers and versions you're using. But a concrete example on your part will help focus the question.